# Nested class selectors not working in next.js sass

Tags: sass, next.js

I'm using scss modules in next.js and want to use nested class selectors like this:

```
.div {
  .x {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

But it seems that this won't work with the following component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './my-component.module.scss'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.div}>
        <span className='x'>ololo</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

For some reason, the styles do not apply to the `<span>` tag.
Whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 8):

You can use **:global** to make nested class work:

```
.div {
  :global .x {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

then you can use like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './my-component.module.scss'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.div}>
        <span className='x'>ololo</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that a Nextjs thing? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: it is a [css-module](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) thing supported by next. Explained [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css) in the nextjs documentation

Answer (score 2):

It was a bit unclear for me, but it seems that I need to extract **both** classes from the module. Like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './my-component.module.scss'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.div}>
        <span className={styles.x}>ololo</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The code above works just fine.

Comment: so what's the point to use scss ? If we need to use styles.div and styles.x, it's like a regular css module.

Comment: Yes that is very lame... not really nesting at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use global differently to the various answers I have seen on this problem and it works great.

```
.headerBlock :global {
    //nothing goes here
    .wrapper {
        //block styling goes here
        &.hasBackground {
        }
        .headerLeft {
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
<header className={styles.headerBlock}>
  <div className="wrapper hasBackground">
    <div className="headerLeft">
```

You only have to add :global after the top class, which is the only one you have to reference using {styles.class}. Child classes then work just by specifying the name as a string.

The only downside is this breaks using & in your scss on direct children of the top parent. Easily solved by adding a wrapper and treating that as the root for your styles.